# fopen in JNI C code get failed for file placed in assets folder in android application

Tags: java, android, c, android-assets

I have kept some files in assets folder of android application.

Now i compile that application and get apk. [when i extract that apk my files are there in assets folder]

Now i install that apk in mobile device

and in That application has some code in c programing with JNI interface.

Now my `fopen()` call in c programming for that file get failed.

```
fopen("myfile","r");
```

I know while installing apk android copy assets file to `/data/data/com.packagename/something`

So does anyone knows that path so i can give it in `fopen()`

or is there any other method to open that file in C programming.

---

If i keep those files in sdcard folder and access like `fopen("/sdcard/myfile","r");` then it works file. But i want to keep those files in assets folder only

Comment: "I know while installing apk android copy assets file to /data/data/com.packagename/something" -- and your proof of this is, what, exactly? AFAIK, assets are not files on the device, but remain packaged in the APK.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the asset manager to access assets in JNI code. It's part of NDK.

http://developer.android.com/ndk/reference/group___asset.html

Something like:

```
EXPORT_API void LoadAsset(char* filename, jobject assetManager){
    AAssetManager* mgr = AAssetManager_fromJava(env, assetManager);
    AAsset* asset = AAssetManager_open(mgr, filename, AASSET_MODE_BUFFER);
    AAsset_read(asset, ...);
}
```

And then in Java something like:

```
LoadAsset("myfile", getContext().getAssetManager());
```

Answer (score 0):

One way I've found is to write a test line in the code, something like:

```
System.out.println("Working Directory = " +
              System.getProperty("user.dir"));
```

Now, if you know where your assets are stored by Android, `/data/data/com.packagename/assets/file.png`, for example, then you will know the reletive or absolute path to the assets. I hope this works for you, it helped me!